# yum install texinfo on CentOS 6.6 (no package)

Tags: installation, centos6, yum, texinfo, rocks

To resolve some dependency to one of my programs, I have to install texinfo on my centos 6.6 system

```
yum install texinfo
```

it resulted to

```
Setting up Install Process
No package texinfo available
Error: Nothing to do
```

I don't know how to resolve this. So far, I've downloaded that [binary rpm.](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/texinfo-tex-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Comment: `yum install binary_rpm_file_location`

Comment: Thanks ! it worked, I installed the i686 (texinfo) version first then followed by x86_64 (texinfo-tex) as my system is x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`texinfo` is provided by the `BASE` repo.

```
Available Packages
Name        : texinfo
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.13a
Release     : 8.el6
Size        : 668 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : Tools needed to create Texinfo format documentation files
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/
License     : GPLv3+
Description : Texinfo is a documentation system that can produce both online
            : information and printed output from a single source file. The GNU
            : Project uses the Texinfo file format for most of its documentation.
            : 
            : Install texinfo if you want a documentation system for producing both
            : online and print documentation from the same source file and/or if you
            : are going to write documentation for the GNU Project.
```

It sounds like you may not have it enabled or configured. Have a check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` Hopefully you have that file. Within the `[base] and [updates]` section check if you have the line `enabled=0` If you do change the `0` to a `1` If you don't have the .repo file at all then create it with the path & file name above then add the following to it;

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Finally do `yum clean all` and you should be good to go.

Comment: This solution worked well. the repo was present but apparently disabled. Did the change from 0 -> 1 and did `yum install texinfo` and proceeded just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$ dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install texinfo

As documented at:
https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/texinfo-6.5-4.el8.x86_64.rpm.html