# Yum update fails -Centos 7 - dockerbuild

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7, yum

I have frequently built docker container using centos 7 as base image. But now I am getting error when I run,

```
RUN yum update add \
    bash \
    && rm -rfv /var/cache/apk/*

ERROR:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
```

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
   upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
   distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
   packages for the previous distribution release still work).
3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
       `yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...`
4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
   will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
   again or use `--enablerepo` for temporary usage:

   ```
   yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
   ```

   or

   ```
   `subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>`
   ```
5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
   Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
   so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
   slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
   compromise:

   ```
   yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
   ```

> Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64 Could not retrieve
>   mirrorlist
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container
>   error was 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org;
>   Name or service not known" The command '/bin/sh -c yum update add
>   bash     && rm -rfv /var/cache/apk/*' returned a non-zero code: 1

I also saw few resolutions to use "dhclient" but this error happens when i do docker-compose build.

Comment: Does `yum` work normally or give the same error about the `base` repo? e.g if you do a `yum install <foo>` or `yum update <foo>`

Comment: i get same error when i do yum install <foo>

Comment: sounds like the `base` repo is broken or missing. Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698625/3788685) which may fix that part of the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem attempting to run the same `Dockerfile`, which fetched several software packages using `yum`, on two different platforms; one macOS, the other an Ubuntu 16.04-based Linux OS (elementaryOS Loki), both using the official packages from docker.com.

<strike>My *theory* is that the Linux package is just more restrictive out of the box, security-wise, than the macOS one. Maybe this is configurable with some kind of `/etc/something` config file, but I don't have the expertise with Docker to say for sure.</strike> **EDIT**: See my comment below.

What I *can* say is there was no additional configuration required for me on macOS (10.11 El Capitan); just `docker build .` worked fine, and `yum` processes from the `Dockerfile` were able to reach all the remote repositories.

In the Ubuntu-derived Linux distro, however, it was necessary to use

```
docker build --network host .
```

followed by

```
docker run -it --network host <image> <command>
```

when I wanted to run a process inside that image which required internet access.

This may be the case for other Debian-derived systems as well.

There are, of course, security considerations which need to be taken into account when allowing a long-running Docker container to communicate through the host network adapter, unrestricted, and one would do well to review [the appropriate documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/) in that regard.

Comment: One potential long-term solution, which does _not_ require `--network host` for every `docker` command line, is mentioned in the official Docker documentation under "Post-installation steps for Linux": disable NetworkManager's `dnsmasq` integration as outlined [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#disable-dnsmasq) (see also [this SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/681993/using-dnsmasq-with-networkmanager)). That's probably not optimal if your host OS is a server for multiple users on a LAN.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that for some reason network behavior in docker varies based on distribution.

Try to use:

```
docker run -d --net mybridge centos
```

or

```
docker network create -d bridge mybridge
docker run -d --net mybridge centos
```

It should start working. Or just edit `/etc/hosts` and add mirror address

```
Name:    mirrorlist.centos.org
Address: 67.219.148.138
```

Comment: Agreed. From my experience there _do_ seem to be differences between distros, or at least OSes. On macOS, there is no additional configuration required to communicate with internet hosts from processes running within Docker containers, using the host's network interface. It was a bit puzzling at first, but I think I prefer having to _manually_ establish a bridge to the host interface, rather than what appears to be an insecure-by-default configuration on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

root cause of the issue is, container proxy settings were wrong. Just corrected the proxy settings at the below location and worked.

/root/.docker/config.json