# Unable to install latest foreman on RHEL 7.4

Tags: docker, puppet, yum, theforeman

Trying to install foreman as per https://theforeman.org/manuals/1.16/index.html#2.1Installation

```
Expected outcome:
```

foreman installed

```
Foreman and Proxy versions:
```

1.16, not sure about proxy server versions

run foreman-installer -v

output:

```
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Systemd start for puppetserver failed!
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] journalctl log for puppetserver:
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] – Logs begin at Tue 2018-04-10 14:26:06 UTC, end at Wed 2018-04-11 16:45:27 UTC. –
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: Failed to load feature test for posix: can’t find user for 0

[ WARN 2018-04-11 16:44:52 verbose]  Compiled catalog for ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x in environment production in 4.15 seconds
[ INFO 2018-04-11 16:44:54 verbose]  Applying configuration version '1523465088'
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose]  Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install foreman-proxy' returned 1: Checksum type 'md5' disabled
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose]  Package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch (foreman)
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose]            Requires: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose]  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose]  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose] /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/execution.rb:285:in `execute'
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose] /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider.rb:101:in `execute'
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose] /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider/package/yum.rb:220:in `install'
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:07 verbose] /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type/package.rb:88:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Puppet>'

[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: Cannot run on Microsoft Windows without the win32-process, win32-dir and win32-service gems: Win32API only supported on win32
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: Puppet::Error: Cannot determine basic system flavour
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: (root) at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/feature/base.rb:40
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: (root) at /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/jruby-1_7.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: invoke at jruby_internal.clj:186
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: invoke at jruby_agents.clj:65
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: invoke at jruby_agents.clj:48
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: invoke at jruby_agents.clj:233
[ERROR 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Apr 11 16:40:45 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[20720]: invokeStatic at internal.clj:389
....................................
[ WARN 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] /Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x]: Dependency Package[foreman-proxy] has failures: true
[ WARN 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] /Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x]: Dependency Package[mod_passenger] has failures: true
[ WARN 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] /Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
[ WARN 2018-04-11 16:45:27 verbose] Applied catalog in 33.51 seconds
[ INFO 2018-04-11 16:45:29 verbose] Puppet has finished, bye!
[ INFO 2018-04-11 16:45:29 verbose] Executing hooks in group post
Something went wrong! Check the log for ERROR-level output

Foreman is running at https://ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x
Initial credentials are admin / 2b7kvQvQAuqGq4P7
Foreman Proxy is running at https://ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x:8443
Puppetmaster is running at port 8140
The full log is at /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman.log
[ INFO 2018-04-11 16:45:29 verbose] All hooks in group post finished
[ INFO 2018-04-11 16:45:29 verbose] Installer finished in 46.166652169 seconds
```

I found an article: https://karloluiten.nl/fix-puppet-failed-to-load-feature-test-for-posix-cant-find-user-for-0/
The fix recommended is:
Has to do with noexec on /tmp . Fix by editing /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver, add something like “-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/puppettmp” , mkdir /var/puppettmp, chmod 1777 /var/puppettmp .

But after i apply the changes to /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver, when i run the foreman-installer -v
the changes ( -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/puppettmp ) are wiped and reverted to default, and puppet server still fails to restart. Any idea how i can permanently modify the configuration and still be able to run foreman-installer?

```
So basically yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install foreman-proxy
fails
```

---

Responding to @user3788685:

```
[root]# yum install foreman-proxy
Checksum type 'md5' disabled
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                        | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                  |  19 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                                  | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
foreman                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
foreman-plugins                                                                                                       | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
local-rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                       | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
local-rhel-7-server-ose-3.4-rpms                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
local-rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                              | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
newrelic                                                                                                              | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
newrelic-infra                                                                                                        | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
puppet5                                                                                                               | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
puppetlabs-deps                                                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
puppetlabs-products                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
rhscl-ruby193-epel-7-x86_64                                                                                           | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
rhscl-ruby200-epel-7-x86_64                                                                                           | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7                                                                                    | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                                                                                      | 3.5 kB  00:00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common                                                                                     | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
(1/7): puppet5/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                      |  73 kB  00:00:00
(2/7): local-rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/primary_db                                                                     | 303 kB  00:00:00
(3/7): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                         | 908 kB  00:00:00
(4/7): rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo                                                     | 2.8 MB  00:00:02
(5/7): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                         | 6.3 MB  00:00:06
(6/7): local-rhel-7-server-rpms/primary_db                                                                            |  39 MB  00:00:21
(7/7): rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/primary_db                                                     |  51 MB  00:00:31
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foreman-proxy.noarch 0:1.16.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(concurrent-ruby) < 2.0 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rubyipmi) >= 0.9.2 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rack) >= 1.1.0 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(concurrent-ruby) >= 1.0 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(sinatra) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rsec) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rkerberos) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rb-inotify) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(gssapi) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(bundler_ext) for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foreman-proxy.noarch 0:1.16.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-bundler_ext.noarch 0:0.4.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(bundler) for package: rubygem-bundler_ext-0.4.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-concurrent-ruby.noarch 1:1.0.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-gssapi.noarch 0:1.1.2-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(ffi) >= 1.0.1 for package: rubygem-gssapi-1.1.2-3.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-rack.noarch 1:1.6.4-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rb-inotify.noarch 0:0.9.7-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rkerberos.x86_64 0:0.1.3-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8(kadm5clnt_mit_8_MIT)(64bit) for package: rubygem-rkerberos-0.1.3-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8()(64bit) for package: rubygem-rkerberos-0.1.3-5.el7.x86_64
---> Package rubygem-rsec.noarch 0:0.4.2-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rubyipmi.noarch 0:0.10.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ipmitool for package: rubygem-rubyipmi-0.10.0-2.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-sinatra.noarch 1:1.4.8-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rack-protection) < 2 for package: 1:rubygem-sinatra-1.4.8-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(tilt) < 3 for package: 1:rubygem-sinatra-1.4.8-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rack-protection) >= 1.4 for package: 1:rubygem-sinatra-1.4.8-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(tilt) >= 1.3 for package: 1:rubygem-sinatra-1.4.8-2.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foreman-proxy.noarch 0:1.16.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package ipmitool.x86_64 0:1.8.18-7.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: OpenIPMI-modalias for package: ipmitool-1.8.18-7.el7.x86_64
---> Package libkadm5.x86_64 0:1.15.1-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-bundler.noarch 0:1.7.8-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(thor) >= 0.19.0 for package: rubygem-bundler-1.7.8-3.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(net-http-persistent) for package: rubygem-bundler-1.7.8-3.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-ffi.x86_64 0:1.9.14-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rack-protection.noarch 0:1.5.3-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-tilt.noarch 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package OpenIPMI-modalias.x86_64 0:2.0.23-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package foreman-proxy.noarch 0:1.16.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3 for package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package rubygem-net-http-persistent.noarch 0:2.8-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-thor.noarch 0:0.19.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch (foreman)
           Requires: rubygem(rake) >= 0.8.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

looking at the already installed gems:

```
[root@ip-10-103-137-14 ~]# gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ansi (1.4.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.16.1)
clamp (1.0.0)
hashie (2.0.5)
highline (1.7.8)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
kafo (2.0.1)
kafo_parsers (0.1.6)
kafo_wizards (0.0.1)
little-plugger (1.1.3)
logging (1.8.2)
multi_json (1.12.1)
powerbar (1.0.17)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (12.3.1)
rdoc (4.0.0)
yajl-ruby (1.3.0)
```

---

So going foward, i installed

```
yum install rubygem-rake-0.9.6-30.el7.noarch.rpm
```

By downloading the rubygem repo manually.

then running

```
yum  install foreman-proxy
```

Package foreman-proxy-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version

then ran

```
foreman-installer -v

[ WARN 2018-04-16 04:54:07 verbose]  Compiled catalog for ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x in environment production in 2.58 seconds
[ INFO 2018-04-16 04:54:09 verbose]  Applying configuration version '1523854445'
[ERROR 2018-04-16 04:54:53 verbose]  Systemd start for puppetserver failed!
[ERROR 2018-04-16 04:54:53 verbose] journalctl log for puppetserver:
[ERROR 2018-04-16 04:54:53 verbose] -- Logs begin at Tue 2018-04-10 14:26:06 UTC, end at Mon 2018-04-16 04:54:53 UTC. --
[ERROR 2018-04-16 04:54:53 verbose] Apr 16 04:50:22 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[31026]: Failed to load feature test for posix: can't find user for 0
[ERROR 2018-04-16 04:54:53 verbose] Apr 16 04:50:22 ip-10-103-137-14.aws.x.x.x puppetserver[31026]: Cannot run on Microsoft Windows without the win32-process, win32-dir and win32-service gems: Win32API only supported on win32
```

so while i am trying to resolve this i came across Docker Image of Foreman, that worked

Comment: What is returned with just `yum install foreman-proxy` - exact/full error details please. Also have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/855030/solved-unable-to-install-foreman-proxy-on-centos-6-9)

Comment: @user3788685 adding the complete trace for  yum install foreman-proxy in the question since its better formatted there

Comment: It looks like you may have an issue with your `updates` repo. I get; `rubygem-rake-0.9.6.33.el7_4` offered when I search from `updates/7/x86_64`. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698625/3788685) may help you out if that is the case. Its for OS6 but Have a check you should have a similar setup & see what happens - if it works I'll write it up as a specific answer for you for OS7.

Comment: @user3788685 updated the additional steps i took in the main question
Systemd start for puppetserver failed!. This could be the /tmp issue but not sure how i can resolve. the resolution is listed here https://karloluiten.nl/fix-puppet-failed-to-load-feature-test-for-posix-cant-find-user-for-0/ but when i apply the changes and run foreman-installer -v the changes i make (-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/puppettmp) gets reverted

Comment: Alas I can't offer any more assistance myself on foreman - sorry. The lines; `Failed to load feature test for posix: can't find user for 0` and `Cannot run on Microsoft Windows without the win32-process, win32-dir and win32-service gems: Win32API only supported on win32` don't seem right tho.